# Is there any option in dpkg-divert to add lines to the existing file instead of replacing it entirely?

Tags: bash, shell, dpkg

I'm creating a debian that will replace a file from another package. I read dpkg-divert is the proper way to handle this situation, however the only option I see is --add which replaces the existing file by mine. I'd like to add only few lines at the end of the existing file (I don't know what's in there and I don't want to change it).
Do I have to do it manually at the preinst? Is there a straight-forward solution? Is my approach just wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your target file is a config file. Those should normally not be touched after they've been generated. Without more information, it's hard to say more, except yes, it does sound like you are trying the wrong approach. What sort of file are we talking about? Which package owns it?

Comment: `dpkg` isn't really designed to do this. This is why so many things have gone to split configuration directories, so a package can simply place its own config file in the directory (eg /etc/xorg.conf.d/).

Comment: I want to change some general options of the lighttpd web server. Replacing the original config file doesn't sound good to me neither, but it seems that dpkg-divert is specially made for this: http://www.debianadmin.com/manpages/dpkgdivertmanpage.htm so I thought that it might be the usual approach (I'm quite new to debian creation)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, this has nothing to do with [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) anyway.

If it’s a conffile (e.g. shipped in `/etc` you indeed **must not** change it). Creating it with `ucf` from a template (in `/usr/share/packagename/`) is the way to go there.

Otherwise, `dpkg-divert` is not the way to do it either, unfortunately. But you can use `postinst` with a `trigger` like this:

- in `postinst`, divert the original file away, with removing in `prerm` of course
- in `postinst`, triggered when the original file is written, concatenate it with your amendments